# iMacro tab and enter

Tags: javascript, firefox, imacros

Hey I am making a script which will auto share some things for me to various groups I am a part of on Facebook. I have it almost completely working except for one thing. When you put the name of a group into facebook you have to physically click it or press "TAB" to make it register before it will let you hit share. (The share is opened in a new window, the right selections are made and the proper group is put in).

```
   pin = "CODE:";
   pin += "SET !ERRORIGNORE YES"+"\n";
   pin += "TAG POS={{i}} TYPE=SPAN ATTR=CLASS:fb&&TXT:" + "\n";
   pin += "WAIT SECONDS=3" +"\n";
   pin += "TAB T=2" + "\n";
   pin += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:Share<SP>on<SP>your<SP>timeline"+"\n";
   pin += "WAIT SECONDS=1" +"\n";
   pin += "TAG POS=2 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:Share<SP>in<SP>a<SP>group"+"\n";
   pin += "WAIT SECONDS=1" +"\n";
   pin += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:u_0_10 ATTR=ID:u_0_l CONTENT=" + " {boards}}"+"\n";
   pin += "WAIT SECONDS=2"+"\n";
   pin += "EVENT TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="+"#u_0_l"+" KEY=9" + "\n";
   pin += "WAIT SECONDS=2"+"\n";
   pin += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=ID:u_0_10 ATTR=NAME:share" +"\n";
   pin += "WAIT SECONDS=3"+"\n";
   pin += "TAB T=1" + "\n";
   pin += "TAB CLOSE" + "\n";
```

A little more info, the page this works on is http://paulalols.outloudlaughs.net/ if anyone can tell me why or how to get the tab button to work, I would be very happy. 
I am using the more advanced options on the recorder but I would like to not have to use it for all of it, just for the one part of entering a key stroke.

As well I am working in selenium to get this done as well, just thought I'd try to do it in macros first.

Comment: Use experimental recording and click the keys on keyboard.

Comment: Experimental recording, is that different than hitting record? When I make my scripts I initially record everything to see what I need to do, then turn it into a js.

Comment: In record options select this option. http://prntscr.com/3j4ygd